# Swiftmailer subject and weird whitespace problem

Tags: php, email, whitespace, phpmailer, swiftmailer

When sending a message with `swiftmailer` or `SmtpMailer`, the subject has a weird whitespace.

The subject should look like this: "Newsletter October 2010 - Hello everyone"
 But looks like this: "Newsletter October 2010 - Hello everyo ne"

The whitespace always comes up the same place.

`PHPmailer` does not have the whitespace, but we need to use swift because of spam.

Hope you can help me.

Thanks,

Troels